# How to get your page to scroll an input element into view when the virtual keyboard covers it?

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, uiwebview, mobile-website

This is done automatically when I load my website in iOS Safari and Chrome, but not done when I load it in cordova. I'd prefer a non-JS solution if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by non-JS? How do you want to achieve it without script?

Comment: Ideally there would be some way to tell iOS to treat keyboard opening in UIWebView just like keyboards in Safari. If that's not possible, then a JS solution is fine.

Comment: Eg on Android it's a setting: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard

with:

```
window.addEventListener 'native.keyboardshow', (e) ->
  cur_height = $('body').height()
  $('body').height cur_height - e.keyboardHeight

window.addEventListener 'native.keyboardhide', (e) ->
  $('body').height '100%'
```